# JQuery - Clone table on first textfield .change event

Tags: jquery, loops

The .change clone works for the first field, but not for the second.  What can I add to my loop?

Thanks.

```
<table>
  <tr> 
     <td><input type="text" id="txtA" name="txtA"></td> 
     <td><input type="text" id="txtB" name="txtB"></td> 
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    var i = 1;
    $("#txtA").change(function() {
       $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
          $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + i });
       }).end().appendTo("table");
       i++;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? As far as I can tell, it doesn't do anything for the second text field because you've only bound `.change()` to `$("#txtA")`.

Comment: Right.  How can I bound the change event to each consecutive txtA2, txtA3, etc..?

Comment: So by "second" do you mean txtA1 or txtB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `.clone()` to `.clone(true)` to also clone event handlers.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LSBAZ/)**

---

If you meant that you want the `change` handler to be bound to both inputs, then just add the ID of the second element to the selector:

```
$("#txtA,#txtB").change(...
```